# How can I see all argument options in R?

Tags: r

This seems like a stupid question, but I have not been able to find the answer by googling.

R Documentation often does not outline all possible values for particular arguments. Is there a command to print that information?

For example, I would like to draw some maps using the function `map()` in the `maps` package. The R Documentation states for the region argument:

> regions: character vector that names the polygons to draw. Each
>   database is composed of a collection of polygons, and each polygon has
>   a unique name. When a region is composed of more than one polygon, the
>   individual polygons have the name of the region, followed by a colon
>   and a qualifier, as in michigan:north and michigan:south. Each element
>   of regions is matched against the polygon names in the database and,
>   according to exact, a subset is selected for drawing. The default
>   selects all polygons in the database.

Is it possible to get a list of the region names?

Comment: Do you want `formals(map)` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can see the arguments and defaults with:

```
args(map)
```

I believe you are looking for elements in the database and not arguments since the map function will not know what database you are passing it. Its default is 'world'.

```
w <- map('world')
str(w) # not necessary, but good to look at
w$names
```

And further:

```
canada <- map(region = 'Canada')
canada$names
```